# LKM Support in Nexus S

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have Nexus S with Android 4.1.2 and i want to insert my custom Loadable-Kernel-Module into it. I have already rooted it. I want to know that

1. whether Nexus S running kernel support LKM already or I have to flash my own kernel with LKM-support and then insert my modules ?
2. I have download Android 2.2 source code and now downloading Samsung-kernel from android.source.com to compile modules for my Nexus S with Android 4.1.2. I want to know that whether I have to download 4.1.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can load your LKM using 'insmod your_lkm.ko' as root. It should work on any android.
2. You probably want to compile the LKM using the kernel that currently on the device
   and not a different version (especially not one with a major version change, e.g. linux version 2.6 and version 3.0)

Comment: I found its solution long ago but thanks for your answer. Your answer is right.